# hibernate not inserting inside composite table

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

since a few hours I am trying to add some information to a composite key table in spring boot.

My classes are:

```
        @Entity
    @Table(name = "[order]")
    public class ReturnOrder {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;
    
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "returnOrder")
        Set<ArticleInOrder> articles;
    
        @Column (name = "customer_id")
        private Long customerId;
    
        @Column (name = "reseller_id")
        private Long reseller;
        
        // Getters and setters
    }
```

- 

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "article_in_order")
public class ArticleInOrder {

    @EmbeddedId
    ArticleInOrderKey id;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("articleId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "article_id")
    Article article;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("orderId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id")
    ReturnOrder returnOrder;

    public int count;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

- 

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "article")
public class Article {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private Long number;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "article")
    Set<ArticleInOrder> articleInOrders;
    
    // getter and setters
}
```

Here is a picture of hibernate: [image]

As you can see it is only inserting inside the order table, and not in my table article_in_order.

A picture when the rows are getting inserted to show that the objects are setted up right:
[image]

Comment: Please also share the code controller/service/repository that performs the order saving

Comment: Didn't think that would be important also. If needed I can add it.

Comment: I think it would be important. What if your code does never set the `articles` property in the `ReturnOrder` object it tries to persist?